# Pass textbox value from child window to parent page in asp with out post back in parent

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I created an Asp application, for finder option child window is used.when we select the finder option is opened, selected value from grid view is showing the text box(eg..id and name).These two text box values pass to parent page, after selection in child page.while passing from child to parent page, parent should not refresh or postback.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using javascript to open the window.  If that is the case, then you can use `window.opener` to put data back into the opening window:

```
 $(window.opener.document).find('#someid').val("Some Value");
```